# Rewrite proposition using equivalence in Coq

Tags: coq

My current environment is:

```
1 subgoal
p1, p2 : Entity -> Prop
H : forall s : Entity, p1 s <-> p2 s
t : Entity
FoS1 : (forall w : Entity, p1 w -> PoS w t) /\
       (forall v : Entity, PoS v t -> exists w : Entity, p1 w /\ OoS v w)
______________________________________(1/1)
(forall w : Entity, p2 w -> PoS w t) /\
(forall v : Entity, PoS v t -> exists w : Entity, p2 w /\ OoS v w)
```

The only difference between the goal and the hypothesis FoS1 is the use p1/p2. I have hypothesis H that says that p1 and p2 are equivalent. Is there a way to rewrite the goal using the equivalence? This way, I could use `assumption FoS1` (or `auto`) to end my proof.

I tried to use `rewrite`, but it doesn’t work. I need to cut the expression until it is very simple, and then I can use `rewrite`. But maybe there is a quicker way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setoid_rewrite` instead.

From Coq manual:

> `rewrite` won't find occurrences inside `forall` that refer to variables bound by the `forall`; use the more advanced `setoid_rewrite` if you want to find such occurrences.

Assume the context you've given, the script below works:

```
Proof.
  repeat (setoid_rewrite <- H).
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: For more information, check out this page: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html#